# How do I render JSON from axios.get on a card?

Tags: json, reactjs, ionic-framework, axios, render

I am able to view the data from the api in my console, but I am having trouble rendering the data I am receiving in the UI. What do I do next?

```
const news = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us'

axios
    .get(news)
    .then(response => {
        const articles = response.data.articles[0].title;
        console.log(articles)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
  });
```

Comment: Typically you'll save it to state and conditionally render UI. What is the response JSON shape and where is your rendering code?

Comment: How would I specifically save a part of the response, such as the title, in a state? 

Right now I just have the JSON in the console log and I am unable to render it anywhere @DrewReese

Comment: It could be as simple as accessing `response.data.articles.title`, but based upon the name it seems `articles` is likely an array of articles, so something like `response.data.articles[0].title`. It's just normal object property accesses at this point. Can you update your question to include this JSON response object?

Comment: @DrewReese once I add the [0].title or just .title the console does not show anything returning. I also updated the code for my axios.get.

Comment: Can you update your question to include this JSON response object so we can see its shape?

Answer (score 2):

In react:

Use effect gets called when it is mounted, calling a custom data() async function to use axios, storing it in local state with useState, then mapping through the state in the renderer

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const NEWS = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us';

const SampleScreen: FC = () => {
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(NEWS);
        const { articles } = res.data;
        if (articles) {
          setNews(articles);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    };
    data();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {news.map(({ title, content, date }) => {
        return (
          <div key={date}>
            <strong>{title}</strong>
            <p>{content}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SampleScreen;
```